# Parse all values from Sqlite column to string Array

Tags: android, sqlite

Hi i am new in Android Sqlite Database. I want to parse all my values from a Sqlite column to an Array. It look's like folllowing:

```
id        name
1         Peter
2         Mary
3         Tom
4         Elsa
```

Android Array:

```
String[] NameArray = new String[4];
Int[] idArray = new Int[4];
```

Comment: Show us your efforts! What've you tried already?

Answer (score 2):

```
            String Table_Name="name of table";
            String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + Table_Name;
            SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
            Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
            cursor.moveToFirst();
            String[] NameArray = new String[cursor.count()];
            String[] idArray = new String[cursor.count()];
            int i = 0;

            while(cursor.moveToNext()){

                String uname = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("name"));
                NameArray [i] = uname;
                String id= cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("id"));
                idArray [i] = id;
                i++;

            }
            db.close();
```